# C++ int main (int argc, char *argv[]) - is argv a c style array?

Tags: c++, arrays, program-entry-point

the following does not compile:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char arr[2][2];
    char **ptr = arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Yet the following does:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **ptr = argv;
    return 0;
}
```

Thus I would conclude that argv is not a c style array which is stored as a single block of memory but rather is some sort of pointer array. Can somebody confirm that?

Thank you and Regards.

Comment: If `argv` was an array of arrays, then the size of the inner arrays would be part of the type (and they'd all have to be the same size).

Comment: `arr` decays to the pointer to arrays with type `char (*)[2]`, which is not the same as a pointer to pointers with type `char**`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct, `argv` is a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers, each of which in turn (except for the last one) is a pointer to the first character in a string of characters giving the respective command line argument.

Function parameters cannot be arrays.

Comment: I deleted my answer about there being no such thing as an array type parameter, because even if that were a thing, it would still work because of array-to-pointer conversion. The main problem is that the inner type is an array, not a pointer.